# How do I use global resources in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a WPF application which I would like to use some static resources in. I have created a Resource Library XAML file which contains a  resource. I have also added a string into the Resources of the project through the Properties panel.

I assumed I could just use these resources with the binding expression:

```
{StaticResource ResourceName}
```

But visual studio is telling me the resources are not found. Do I have to include some form of reference in my XAML? The examples I have seen only include resources locally such as:

```
<Window.Resources>, <Page.Resources> etc
```

I don't want to include the resources locally because I want them to be available to multiple parts of the application.

Answer (score 13):

Put them in the App.xaml :)

> In each WPF application there is an
>   App.xaml (and its corresponding code
>   file, App.xaml.cs or App.xaml.vb)
>   which works as a global file for
>   application wide declarations. You can
>   use this file to declare a constant
>   look and feel across your application.
>   For example you can declare a default
>   red background for all buttons in an
>   application.

http://www.microsoft.com/emea/msdn/thepanel/en/articles/introduction_wpf.aspx

Comment: In my project this was named by default as Application.xaml. It's a good answer but can I not make the styles in my ResourceLibrary available globally?

Answer (score 5):

You can create a dictionary of global resources and include its path in app.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/YourProject;Component/YourXamlFile.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

Now all your resources in the YourXamlFile.xaml will be visible globally in your project.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the section on "static resource lookup behavior" [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613.aspx).  Anything in the application's resource dictionary (i.e. `Application.Resources`) is available globally.  Whenever you look up a resource with a given key, and the key isn't used anywhere in the hierarchy of local resource dictionaries, the one in the application's dictionary will be returned.

To populate the application's resource dictionary in XAML, find the XAML file for the application (usually App.xaml) and add an `Application.Resources` element.

Comment: I can understand how the lookup behavior works its way up to this Application.Resources area but how would I use a resource that is set on the project. E.g. Right click project file, click properties, go to resources. I mean the resources in there. The are not included in my Application.Resources and neither is my Resource Library xaml file.

Comment: So I've used..

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/Resources/Styles.xaml" />
    </Application.Resources>

And that has solved one of the problems by allowing me to use the Styles in my external resource dictionary. Still struggling on the actual project resource though.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you were trying to use project resources.  Project resources and resource dictionaries are really two different things.  If you have (for instance) an image that's a project resource, you can get it into the resource dictionary via `<Image x:Key="SomeKey" Source="URI_of_resource"/>`.  But not every WPF class has a `Source` property that can load it from the project resources.

Comment: So what about my string resource. Is it a bad idea to put this in the project resources. Should I stick it straight in the Resource Dictionary? Because I don't know how to do that. A Silverlight business application will use resources from .resx files. And the project resources file in wpf is also .resx so I know you can use a StaticResource from it. I just can't see how.

Comment: Oh, if you're using the VS resource editor, just make sure that you've set the resources' access modifier to Public.  Then you can get them via markup in XAML by using `{x:Static local:Properties.Resources.MyString}`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add my 2 cents here.

I also wanted to use global resources, but I use a custom Application class, so I couldn't just put it in the App.xaml.

I created a Resources.xaml in my root location, and then did this:

```
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("/MyWpfClient;component/Resources.xaml", UriKind.Relative) });
```

But be warned, the Resource.xaml MUST have the Build Action to 'Page'. When it didn't it couldn't find some types I used as converters.