# How To Apply DataGrid.Resources To All DataGrids

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have created a WPF project with multiple DataGrid controls.  I want them to display selected rows in the normal style even when the DataGrid loses focus.  The code below works, but I want an easy way to apply this to all the DataGrids in the project without manually inserting this code into every DataGrid in the project.  Can this be done in the app.xaml file or some other central resource?

```html
            <DataGrid Name="dgStores" AutoGenerateColumns="True" AutoGeneratedColumns="DataGrid_AutoGeneratedColumns" >
                <DataGrid.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="DodgerBlue"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="White"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="DodgerBlue"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="White"/>
                </DataGrid.Resources>
            </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Take a look to this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911824/how-do-i-use-global-resources-in-wpf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a style that targets DataGrid and add your resources to the style's resources and place this above the DataGrids in the visual tree (e.g. App.xaml):

```
<Style TargetType="DataGrid">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="DodgerBlue"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="White"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="DodgerBlue"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="White"/>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Comment: Glen, That's awesome! It works perfectly. That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks